# `<module:Formula>': undefined method `mattr_accessor'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby 2.1.1, rail 4.1.0, formula gem 1.0.0. And I;m getting this error when I try to do this:

irb
require 'formula'

Error:

```
chadd:homebrew-openmw-master chadd$ ruby openmw-bullet.rb
/Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formula-1.0.0/lib/formula.rb:8:in `<module:Formula>': undefined method `mattr_accessor' for Formula:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formula-1.0.0/lib/formula.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from openmw-bullet.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running this in a rails console or a standard irb? If irb why not try and require 'active_support' since formula relies 100% on rails. Not sure if it needs other dependencies too. You will have to require these prior to formula.

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

`mattr_accessor` method is provided by rails's activesupport component, its not the part of ruby, hence require 'active_support' in your script and then try.

Comment: Well the thing is this is a pre-created and popular gem. So I should be able to require it in my irb

Comment: https://github.com/ksylvest/formula#requirements, can u read the requirements and see that its not tested with rails 4??, try this with rails versions specified.

Comment: I'll try that. and comment back